# Queue.Queue vs semaphores, locks, etc. in multithreaded Python code

Tags: python, multithreading

> The principal challenge of
>   multi-threaded applications is
>   coordinating threads that share data
>   or other resources. To that end, the
>   threading module provides a number of
>   synchronization primitives including
>   locks, events, condition variables,
>   and semaphores.
>
> While those tools are powerful, minor
>   design errors can result in problems
>   that are difficult to reproduce. So,
>   the preferred approach to task
>   coordination is to concentrate all
>   access to a resource in a single
>   thread and then use the Queue module
>   to feed that thread with requests from
>   other threads. Applications using
>   Queue.Queue objects for inter-thread
>   communication and coordination are
>   easier to design, more readable, and
>   more reliable.

It, basically, states to use Queue.Queue for inter-thread communication and coordination, instead of the powerful tools such as semaphores, locks, etc.

My question is, what's the drawback of the suggested method?  When should one use the more "powerful tools" instead, and why?

**Edit**

To be clear, I know what semaphores are.  I was just wondering why the Python documentation suggests to use the Queue.Queue method instead of the "powerful tools" -- I'm simply using the documentation's own verbiage, not coming up with my own.

Comment: Just a quick clarification question, do you know what semaphores are?

Comment: I'm not sure how that's a clarification question, however, yes, I do know what they are.

Comment: I think we were thrown a bit by the "powerful methods" term you used, as they are not methods. The documentation is quite correct to name them as tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm not sure I'd consider semaphores and locks "more powerful methods", as you suggest.

Queues are generally a higher-order abstraction.  In other words, you could use semaphores and locks to build thread-safe queues.

Which you'd use where depends on your application.  Queues are good for passing "work" between threads and processes, and semaphores/locks are good for protecting critical sections or shared resources, so only one thread can access at a time.

Comment: To add to payne's response. Semaphores, locks, condition variables, and events are not methods at all. They are structures and control variables that allow synchronization and data protection between threads. Queues abstract some of these away so that it is easier to get threads up and running. Otherwise all your time is going to be spent debugging poorly implemented threads.

Comment: I didn't suggest they were powerful tools, the documentation did.  I just wanted to better understand what the documentation was trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

[Take a look at the source code for Python's thread-safe queue](http://svn.python.org/view/python/branches/release27-maint/Lib/Queue.py?view=markup). The queue class builds a useful abstraction from 3 Conditions and a Lock, *correctly*.

I wouldn't say coordination is the hardest problem. In shared-state multithreading the hardest thing is preventing threads from "sharing". You always have to look out for non-deterministic behaviour due to threads accidentally sharing and stomping on each other's data.

So, I recommend you don't use threads at all. You should use the lower-level tools when you feel you haven't spent enough time tracking down heisenbugs, but if there's any way you can get away with using a simple queue, go for it.

Comment: Link not working